# Extraer una cadena de texto dentro de la separación de otro caracteres - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, substring

Buen día a la comunidad, Tengo muchas dudas. Quiero realizar lo siguiente:

tengo esta cadena en una columna
=>     '1500,1;500;2020-05-16,2;500;2020-06-16,3;500;2020-07-16'
Quiero obtener este grupo por separado:

- 1;500;2020-05-16
- 2;500;2020-06-16
- 3;500;2020-07-16

Poder separar ese grupo que están entre coma y coma "**,**" y luego poder presentarlo así:
=>  |001|500|2020-05-16|
|002|500|2020-06-16|
|003|500|2020-07-16|

He usado **Substring** y **Charindex** pero sin resultado alguno. Espero alguna ayuda o idea para poder solucionarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con esta sentencia, saco cuantas comas existen:

```
SELECT (len(desc_metodopago) - DATALENGTH(replace(desc_metodopago, ',', ''))) / len(',') [comas] from DOCUMENTOVENTA(NOLOCK) WHERE tipodocu = @tipo And nro_efact = @numero
```

He aquí para meter en ciclo while, validar cuantas comas e imprimir resultado tal como detalle en el inicio de mi pregunta.

```
declare @contador INT = 0,@num_cuota char(1), @val_cuota varchar(100),@fec_cuota varchar(10);


while @contador <  (len(@desc_metodopago) - DATALENGTH(replace(@desc_metodopago, ',', ''))) / len(',') begin set @contador = @contador +1 print @contador end;
```

De antemano, gracias por su respuesta y/o apoyo.

Comment: Deberías de exponer, un ejemplo reproducible, para que podamos ayudarte y tu respuesta no sea concebida como de mala calidad y por esto cerrada. Como supongo que esto no será para una sola cadena, sino para una columna de alguna sentencia o tabla, entonces, deberías de exponer, por ejemplo, la sentencia de creación de la tabla y rellenarla con datos de muestra. Por otro lado, la solución no es complicada. Si cumples tú parte, seguro que te podremos ayudar.

Comment: Edite e incluí mas información

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los datos que has añadido, no son lo esperado y no aportan demasiada información.

```
CREATE TABLE DOCUMENTOVENTA 
    (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
     DESC_METODOPAGO VARCHAR(1000)
     );
```

Insertamos una fila.

```
INSERT INTO DOCUMENTOvENTA (DESC_METODOPAGO)
VALUES
('1500,1;500;2020-05-16,2;500;2020-06-16,3;500;2020-07-16');
```

Ahora con el escenario creado, lo primero es utilizar algo, que nos permita partir el cada dato por un separador. Existen muchas funciones que realizan esto. Yo voy a utilizar delimitedSplit8k, la cual puedes consultar como se implementa en este artículo.

[Delimited Split 8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
```

La función nos sirve para partir una cadena en trozos, por un separador.

Luego por lo que veo de lo expuesto, tenemos una primera fila, con un valor, que a priori es descartable (parece el total de los tres pagos). Y luego las tres filas.

```
WITH r AS (
    SELECT * FROM
            DOCUMENTOvENTA D 
        CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(d.desc_metodoPago,',') fn
)
Select * from r;
```

[image: Resultado 1]

Esta parte de la query nos serviría, para partir por la "," de manera que ya tenemos las filas de itemNumber 2, 3, 4 para trabajar el resultado esperado.

Luego la solución podría ser:

```
WITH r AS (
    SELECT * FROM
            DOCUMENTOvENTA D 
        CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(d.desc_metodoPago,',') fn
)
Select CONCAT('|', REPLACE((CONCAT('00', r.Item)),';','|'),'|') 
from r 
where ItemNumber > 1;
```

[image: Result]

Como ves, no hace falta hacer bucles.

Si hubiera más de 9 pagos, habría que buscar una solución para el tema de añadir ceros por la izquierda.

---- Solución si tienes más de dos dígitos, en los pagos.

```
INSERT INTO DOCUMENTOVENTA (DESC_METODOPAGO)
VALUES
('1500,1;500;2020-05-16,2;500;2020-06-16,3;500;2020-07-16'),
('1500,10;500;2020-05-16,11;500;2020-06-16,12;500;2020-07-16');
```

Aunque los "códigos" empiezan en 10, es igual de válido que si hubiera antes los correspondientes.

```
WITH r AS (
    SELECT * FROM
            DOCUMENTOVENTA D 
        CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(d.desc_metodoPago,',') fn
)--, r2 as (
    SELECT R.ID, R.ITEM as itemAnt, FN2.ITEM, fn2.ItemNumber
        FROM R
        CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(r.item, ';') FN2
        where r.ItemNumber >1
```

Despedazamos cada línea en sus correspondientes trozos
[image: Res2]

Luego cogemos el item que le corresponde a la línea itemNumber1 y le añadimos 00 por la izquierda, para poder luego obtener los 3 caracteres de la derecha, de manera que en la que sea por ejemplo un 12 será 0012 y cogeremos solo los tres más a la derecha de esa cadena.

De la salida solo necesitamos la línea itemNumber1, la cual formaremos por su contenido de item1 y la concatenación con itemSinId

```
WITH r AS (
    SELECT * FROM
            DOCUMENTOVENTA D 
        CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(d.desc_metodoPago,',') fn
), r2 as (
    SELECT R.ID, R.ITEM as itemAnt, FN2.ITEM, fn2.ItemNumber
        FROM R
        CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(r.item, ';') FN2
        where r.ItemNumber >1
), r3 as (
    SELECT  r2.ID
          , case when r2.ItemNumber = 1 then concat('00',cast(r2.item as varchar(2))) ELSE R2.ITEM END AS ITEM1
          , R2.ITEM
          , REPLACE((RIGHT(R2.itemAnt,len(r2.itemAnt)-(CHARINDEX(';',R2.ItemAnt)))),';','|') AS itemSinId
          , R2.ItemNumber
    FROM R2 
) 
SELECT R3.ID,CONCAT('|',RIGHT(R3.ITEM1,3),'|',R3.itemSinId,'|')  FROM R3 
WHERE R3.ItemNumber = 1;
```

[image: Result]

Ahora tienes el id, de cada fila, y los valores aunque sean mayores de 9.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta maestro, pero si necesito sacar por id, ósea ¿para sacar por cada que le pertenezca cada cuota a un id o documento? 
WITH r AS (
    SELECT * FROM
            DOCUMENTOvENTA D 
        CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(d.desc_metodoPago,',') fn
)
Select 'CUO|' + REPLACE('Cuota00'+ r.Item,';','|')+'|'
from r 
where ItemNumber > 1 and nro_efact=@num_efact and tipodocu=@tipodocu;

Es lo que agregue e intente. Espero sea lo correcto, muchas gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: Eso si seria buscar una solución para cuando sea mas de 9 cuotas. Por ejemplo:
12 Cuotas, 18 Cuotas.

Comment: La solución de más de 9 cuotas está implementada. Todo lo que le anexas al cte no se lo que significa, porque no has dado ningún dato. No se que es nro_efact ni que valores puede tomar. No se que contiene @num....etc,.,etc.... en eso, sin un escenario claro, no te puedo ayudar.

Comment: Se implemento correctamente. Lo de nro_efact eso lo adicione en el where, filtrando por cada registro. Una solución mas clara, limpia que esta, es un montón. Gracias una vez mas. Sigo aprendiendo mucho mas.